# colorbox loading issue with ie7

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using jquery colorbox for pop up window but after click on link it take too much time and browser works slowly. It happen with only ie7 can u help me
my code is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.contact-form').click(function(){
      jQuery(this).colorbox({ onClosed:true, width: 652, height: 460, inline:true, href:     "#appliction_form" , scrolling: false});
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where you are going wrong because I couldn't reproduce the error.  Using the code you have there in a test page, IE7 worked fine and without the delay you mentioned.  I can offer a couple pointers, though.

First, the `onClosed` option expects a function to run when the colorbox is closed, so you can remove `onClosed:true` as it is ignored.

Also, although it doesn't hurt to put the colorbox call inside a click handler, it's not necessary when using colorbox in the normal way as you are.  By doing it "the colorbox way", you can shave off a few milliseconds of execution time and a few bytes.  Not very interesting, really, but more importantly your code is leaner and more readable:

```
$('.contact-form').colorbox({width: 652, height: 460, inline: true, href: "#appliction_form", scrolling: false});
```

Lastly, you can use `jQuery("#selector")`, but again you can make your code leaner by just using `$("#selector")`.  In jQuery, `jQuery == $`.

I doubt that'll solve your problem, but start there, then mabye you could also post the html you are using for the link to colorbox and your form.  You might also consider making a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can see the error in action.